# Disable changelog for apt-get upgrade?

Tags: upgrade, apt, xubuntu

I'm on a relatively slow network, also I don't really care about changelogs, but each time I'll wait for longtime till updates are installed, just for loading changelogs from remote server.

How can I disable this feature?

Seems that `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d` is only suitable for changing the url of that server.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

By default no changelog is downloaded prior to packages download.
Once downloaded a package to install/upgrade, the changelog is located inside the package itself, so there is no further network use.

It is possible that you have `apt-listchanges` installed, that cause your problem, though it is not installed by default. If it is so, remove it and your problem is solved.